# unable to get access Grafana from browser which is running on kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes-helm, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter, grafana-api

I need a little help if someone can advise where I am doing some mistake.
I am trying to Setup Prometheus & Grafana Monitoring on Kubernetes Using Helm.
Installation of Prometheus and Grafana done successfully.
[Installation of Prometheus and Grafana done successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYRj6.png)

All the pods and services running as expected
[All the pods and services running as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f80Gv.png)

Both Grafana and Prometheus Servers up and running on respective ports.
[Both Grafana and Prometheus Servers up and running on respective ports.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DvVa.png)

However, when I want to access Grafana server from browser then facing issue.
I suppose that the obvious reason is that we don’t have Node Port exposed in Grafana which is necessary to get access from outside.
We can see in last screen shot that Grafana server showing internal cluster IP but not the Node Port IP
To get Node Port exposed I use this :  Kubectl expose service grafana-server --type=Nodeport --target-port=3000 --name=grafana-server-ext
However still not getting NodePort so unable to get access Grafana using browser.

Comment: Hi @coolbaba, the screenshots are not showing as images but rather as links.
Anyway, the installation comes along with some network policies that prevent access via nodeport. You will need to delete them to access both via the browser. This is however not recommended for production

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way, but a quick dirty way to expose it (for testing) can be achieved with `kubectl port-forward`.

```
kubectl --namespace <yournamespace> port-forward svc/<nameofyougrafanaservice> <portonlocalmachine>:<portofserviceink8s> --address 0.0.0.0
```

exmpl.

```
kubectl --namespace monitoring port-forward svc/grafana-1654184440 30001:3000 --address 0.0.0.0
```

This will open the port on your local machine from which you are running the `kubectl port-forward` and you can reach it on url `http://<YOUR_LOCAL_MACHINE_IP>:30001`

The command will occupy the terminal

Also, firewall settings on that local machine should permit connections from outside, you need to open the port `30001`

Answer (score 0):

There are network policies that are blocking this.
You can view all of them by running the command below;

```bash
kubectl get networkpolicies -n monitoring
```

You may proceed to delete all of them or preferably only that for grafana. 
Note that deleting any of these network policies is **not recommended in production**. Run the command below to delete grafana network policy

```bash
kubectl -n monitoring delete networkpolicies.networking.k8s.io grafana
```

or run the one below to delete all the network policies in the monitoring namespace.

```bash
kubectl -n monitoring delete networkpolicies.networking.k8s.io --all
```

That should enable you access the Grafana through Nodeport in your browser.